# Play audio from a direct link

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm working on a mobile device running iOS.

I have a DIRECT download link to an audio file (when I open it on desktop the download starts immediately). I try this but it plays only one time.

```
<script>var audio = new Audio("'+downloadUrl+'");</script> <button onclick="audio.play();">Play</button>
```

I also try to catch it with an `<iframe>` but it plays only one time.

When I use `<audio>` ,"streaming" appears and I have the same problem : [image: Audio Streaming]

I think it's because my file is not saved on my phone. So how can I fix it, so that it plays as required.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at the [*HTMLMediaElement*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#See_also) DOM interface and [*Media Events*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Media_events)

```
var audio = new Audio(downloadUrl);

audio.addEventListener('ended', function () {
    audio.currentTime = 0; // seek to position 0 when ended playing
    /* // alternatively, not sure about compatibility
    audio.fastSeek(0);
    */
});
```

If you wanted it to loop rather than be playable again, set *loop* to `true` instead.

Comment: it doesn't work; I think it's not the problem because when I try : <iframe src="'+downloadUrl+'"/></iframe> it also play one time.

Comment: it is still not working with loop="true" I think the "streaming" is the problem.